# sizeof reporting wrong value

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a "column" elements count from my own structure using `sizeof(_test.header.columns)/sizeof(struct _column)`. Unfortunately I'm always getting it as `0`, because the `sizeof(_test.header.columns)` is always `4`. Here is the code:

```
struct _column{
    char title[40];
    int length;
};

struct test_struct{

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
    }header;

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
    }details;

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
    }end;
};

struct test_struct _test = {

    .header = {
        .columns = {
            {
                "a",
                1,
            },
            {
                "ab",
                2,
            },
        },
    },
    .details = {
        .columns = {
            {
                "b",
                2,
            },
            {
                "bc",
                3,
            },
        },
    },
    .end = {
        .columns = {
            {
                "c",
                3,
            },
            {
                "cd",
                4,
            },
        },
    },
};

void testme(){
    char buff[20];
    itoa(sizeof(_test.header.columns)/sizeof(struct _column),buff,sizeof(buff));
    MessageBoxA(NULL,buff,NULL,NULL);
}
```

please help me to resolve the problem, thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using `sizeof` on pointers, not arrays.

Comment: I used "struct _column* columns;" declaration for declaring columns as array of _column, so if that is false, so how to correct it?

Comment: are you looking at the output from `testme()`, are your parameters in the correct order for MessageBoxA... i don't know what they are... why not use `snprintf(buffer, 20, "%d",number)`

Comment: This code as currently written shouldn't compile, it's not valid C to initialize pointers this way.

Comment: all the testme() is correct, now I like to know how to make my "struct _column* columns" declaration correct in order to be recognized as an array and not pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to do an approach like the following in which you do the same kind of initialization however you include as part of it the column count itself.

```
struct _column{
    char title[40];
    int length;
};

struct test_struct{

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
        int    nColumns;
    }header;

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
        int    nColumns;
    }details;

    struct{
        struct _column* columns;
        int    nColumns;
    }end;
};

struct _column headerColumns [] = {
            {
                "a",
                1
            },
            {
                "ab",
                2
            }
        };

struct _column detailColumns[] = {
            {
                "b",
                2
            },
            {
                "bc",
                3
            },
        };

struct _column endColumns [] = {
            {
                "c",
                3
            },
            {
                "cd",
                4
            }
        };

struct test_struct _test = {
    { headerColumns, sizeof(headerColumns)/sizeof(headerColumns[0])},
    { detailColumns, sizeof(detailColumns)/sizeof(detailColumns[0])},
    { endColumns, sizeof(endColumns)/sizeof(endColumns[0])}
};
```

Comment: My pleasure.  it was a short and pleasant interlude from my work.

Comment: @user3407088, if this provides the answer you are looking for, please mark this as the answer.  I also noticed that you have at least one other question that has an answer but is not marked as answered.  marking as answered increases the rep of the person who created the answer and also marks the question as one that others may learn from as well.  So it is a good idea to mark an answer on any question that has a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it fails is that you're checking the sizeof on a pointer, which returns the size of the pointer, NOT of the actual Array the memory address points to.

If you know the maximum length of the array, you can declare it as such:

```
_column[ integerSize ]
```

But then if you knew the size, you wouldn't be querying it using sizeof, I'd think ;-) You could extend the struct by adding another property of an int type that describes the size of the columns array ?

Comment: *sizeof on a pointer... returns the size of the memory address it points to*; this is misleading at best (downright wrong if you ask me). It simply returns the size of a pointer, usually a small power of 2, like 2, 4 or 8,

Comment: @Jens : you're right, I updated it to avoid confusion as it was indeed a blatant lie :)